# CSS - Navigation menu hover causing flickering effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please take a look at this page: http://www.staging.turtlerush.co.uk/sumas/

The Nav / Sub Nav CSS seems to be causing the hover menu to flicker in all cases EXCEPT when the page is fully scrolled to the top. So in other words, it works at first but as you scroll down the flickering starts.

I believe this is a problem with the nav ui element "clashing" with another but am struggling to fix.....

Probably a bit too much code to just paste in here but happy to if needed.

Any help?

Comment: Please post your code (and maybe a fiddle) here so SO is indepened from external sources

Comment: Can you share a fiddle link to have a look at your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS code to `.kopa-background`:

```
.kopa-background {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

pointer events specify what to do when you click on the element.

This is a little explanation of this CSS property: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

Comment: thanks, this is a partial fix, it certainly stops the flickering. The page still seems very laggy and there is a opacity enabled color appearing over the whole site on hover.....which isn't ideal.

Comment: The opacity color is the .kopa-background <div>. If you want to remove the opacity delete it.